# Symfony 2 routing with an url as argument

Tags: url, symfony, routes

I've got some troubles when trying to pass an Url as argument in Symfony2.

My routing.yml has this pattern : `pattern:  mark/{date}/{url}`

When i'm trying to go to : `/web/app_dev.php/mark/1307374717828/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Fhome%2F`

I've got a not found page, it seems that it doesn't look to symfony because I haven't the problem of "route not matching".

So how to pass an url as an argument ?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't as elegant a use of routing as being able to say pattern: mark/{date}/{url}, but you could just look for the 'url' part as a query parameter.

(in routing.yml)

```
_testurlthing:
    pattern: /mark/{date}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestUrlBundle:Url:mark }
```

(in AcmeTestUrlBundle/Controllers/UrlController.php)

```
public function markAction($date)
{
  $url = $this->get('request')->get('url');
  return new Response("sending you to $url");
}
```

Now you can link to `/web/app_dev.php/mark/1307374717828?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Fhome%2F`

Or using twig:

```
{{ path('_testurlthing', { 'date': 1307374717828, 'url': 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Fhome%2F' }) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Symfony does not match the character "/"; You have to specifically allow it as described [here in the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Comment: While the link here is helpful, it would be better to copy the relevant portions here, also. [Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)